# How to mute a member with multiple roles using JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js, fs

im fairly new to Javascript and have been messing around discord.js. I've been trying to get this Discord bot but  I've been getting stuck. I am trying  to save the members role cache onto an object list which would save onto a json file using fs. If the bot unmute the member, then the saved roles would be reapplied back. So far, I was able to get the timed mute to mute the mentioned member and apply the roles back. However, I keep running into an error if I just use the unmute command.

Here is what I have so far for mute.js:

```
const ms = require("ms");
const fs = require("fs");
//let cachedUserRoles = {};
let cachedUserRoles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./roles.json", "utf-8"));
module.exports = {
  name: "mute",
  description: "Mute a member",
  execute(message, args) {
    let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
      (role) => role.name === "Mute"
    );
    const target =
      message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
    let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
    let cachedUserRoles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./roles.json", "utf-8"));
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
      return message.channel.send(
        "You do not have the permission to manage messages"
      );

    if (target) {
      if (memberTarget.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === "Mute"))
        return message.channel.send("User is already muted!");
      cachedUserRoles[memberTarget] = memberTarget.roles.cache;
      if (!args[1]) {
        fs.writeFile(
          "./roles.json",
          JSON.stringify(cachedUserRoles, null, 4),
          (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
          }
        );
        memberTarget.roles
          .set([])
          .then((target) => target.roles.add(muteRole))
          .catch(console.err);
        message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> ℎ  `);
        return;
      }
      if (isNaN(ms(args[1]))) {
        message.channel.send("    /ℎ//");
        return;
      }
      fs.writeFile(
        "./roles.json",
        JSON.stringify(cachedUserRoles, null, 4),
        (err) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
        }
      );
      memberTarget.roles
        .set([])
        .then((memberTarget) => memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole))
        .catch(console.err);
      //memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
      message.channel.send(
        `<@${memberTarget.user.id}> ℎ    ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`
      );
      setTimeout(function () {
        memberTarget.roles
          .set(cachedUserRoles[memberTarget])
          .catch(console.error);
        //memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
        memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
        message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}>ℎ  `);
        cachedUserRoles = {};
        fs.writeFile(
          "./roles.json",
          JSON.stringify(cachedUserRoles, null, 4),
          (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
          }
        );
      }, ms(args[1]));
    } else {
      message.chanel.send("'  !");
    }
  },
};
```

and here is my unmute.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
let cachedUserRoles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./roles.json", "utf-8"));

module.exports = {
  name: "unmute",
  description: "Unmute a member",
  execute(message, args) {
    const target = message.mentions.users.first();
    let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
      (role) => role.name === "Mute"
    );

    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
      return message.channel.send(
        "You do not have the permission to manage messages"
      );

    if (target) {
      let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
      if (!memberTarget.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === "Mute"))
        return message.channel.send("User is not muted!");

      memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
      memberTarget.roles.set(cachedUserRoles[memberTarget]);
      // console.log(rolesList[memberTarget]);
      message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> ℎ  `);
      cachedUserRoles = {};
      fs.writeFile(
        "./roles.json",
        JSON.stringify(cachedUserRoles, null, 4),
        (err) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
        }
      );
    } else {
      message.chanel.send("'  !");
    }
  },
};
```

The error I am getting is

```
(node:9796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
roles[0]: Value "{'guild': '259552722242633728', 'id': '360211881228763138', 'name': 'Alright People', 'color': 3066993, 'hoist': True, 'rawPosition': 4, 'permissions': 1849155265, 'managed': False, 'mentionable': True, 'deleted': False, 'createdTimestamp': 1505951604898}" is not snowflake.
roles[1]: Value "{'guild': '259552722242633728', 'id': '259552722242633728', 'name': '@everyone', 'color': 0, 'hoist': False, 'rawPosition': 0, 'permissions': 1024, 'managed': False, 'mentionable': False, 'deleted': False, 'createdTimestamp': 1481952591239}" is not snowflake.
```

I have searched up the following posts for solutions as well:

[How to add a role with an ID that is saved in an JSON file discord.js v12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63745937/how-to-add-a-role-with-an-id-that-is-saved-in-an-json-file-discord-js-v12)

[How to remove all roles and add one role on discord bot, and then remove the added role and restore previous roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974984/how-to-remove-all-roles-and-add-one-role-on-discord-bot-and-then-remove-the-add)

But I'm still getting errors, most commonly the

```
TypeError[INVALID_TYPE]:Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following line returns the error.

```js
memberTarget.roles.set(cachedUserRoles[memberTarget]);
```

If you're trying to add a role to the member, please keep in mind that here you're just changing the cache and that a Discord.js collection is just an extension of a Map, which needs a value when set.

Here's [the right way](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) to add a role to a member.

```js
memberTarget.roles.add(JSON.parse(cachedUserRoles[memberTarget]).id);
```

Read more in the [corresponding docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager).

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking over the code. I just tried to test that line but its giving me a TyperError: Cannot read property of 'id of undefined. I also tried  memberTarget.roles.add(cachedUserRoles[memberTarget]); but it gave me another error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.

Comment: What is confusing to me is that I am able to unmute from the setInterval function so I thought that the same lines would work in a different module.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I forgot to parse it. That's because you're not giving objects, but strings of objects. See `JSON.parse()` to reverse `JSON.stringify()`. Editing my post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting an error even with your edited post. This is the error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: It would be really helpful to give the origin of the error. Check your JSON file.

Comment: The roles.json file generally contains the roles here: cachedUserRoles[memberTarget] = memberTarget.roles.cache. I'm not sure where the origin of the error is from but I do agree that it might be from the unmute

Comment: Well, it seems like something went wrong in your file, since JSON.parse() (I guess it's it) threw an error.

Comment: I did some digging and it seems that it's throwing that error because the object is being parsed twice.